# Angular Material Table not showing array data inside dataSource object

Tags: angular, angular-material

Example of behavior:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ctyf9w

Why am I unable to show the data with *ngFor? Is there any example in some docs on how to show the data and rowspan accordinly the other columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not using ngFor correctly. You don't need the index in your case. Change your code from:

```
<div *ngFor="let price of product.prices; let i = index;">        
    {{ price[i].price }}
</div>
```

To:

```
<div *ngFor="let price of product.prices">        
    {{ price.price }}
</div>
```

Here is your [working forked project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dzixsx)